# How to put certain instances of a text file to a list in python

Tags: python

This is what a part of the txt file looks like:

3/Kingsbury Dr/Waterdale Rd/Bundoora

4/Crissane Rd/Waterdale Rd/Heidelberg West

I just want to get the second element which is the bus stop (eg Kingsbury Dr, Crissane Rd) instance in a list. Here is what I have tried so far and not sure how to put the second element in a list

```py
def loadData():
    with open('BusRoute250.txt', 'r') as f:
        busStopList = []
        f_line = f.readline()
        while f_line:
            file_line_lst = list(f_line.strip().split('/'))
            f_line = f.readline()
            for f_line in file_line_lst:
                busStopList.append()
                print(busStopList)
```

The link for txt file contents: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ah1EAhro_5-pgqIDylFSjTyHI9fvylfErB8pFNZb36A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def loadData():
    with open('BusRoute250.txt', 'r') as f:
        bus_stops = []
        for line in f:
            elements = line.strip().split('/')
            if len(elements) > 0:
                bus_stops.append(elements[1])

    return bus_stops

#call function and print:
result = loadData()
print('\n'.join(result))   # print as a column
```

You do not need to explicitly call `readline` for this purpose.  Here we will use a for loop to iterate the file one line at a time, check that the line contains fields, and build the list from each of the second fields.

This is an approach that does not call for external libraries.  But if you plan to do any amount of work with delimited text, I would suggest starting to learn Python `pandas`.

Comment: Thanks for this! How can I print this list? I tried and I couldnt get it to print
Also Ill look into pandas :)

Comment: @Malan: see extra lines in my answer.  That will turn the list into a string, with each element separated by a newline. When printed, it will print a column.  Note that will be longer than most monitors.  You can adapt to your needs with other types of join if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the second element of the list formed in the result of `split('/')` operation.

```py
busStopList.append(file_line_lst[1])
```

The `while` loop is a bit wrong. It should be like this:

```py
while f_line:
    file_line_lst = list(f_line.strip().split('/'))
    busStopList.append(file_line_lst[1])
    f_line = f.readline()
```